# Is it possible to rehash Laravel hash password using bcrypt js?

Tags: node.js, laravel, bcrypt

I'm new in node.js and I'm creating a Restful API. How I can rehash the created password from  https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/hashing using Bcrypt for me to able to check whether the password I input is correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to re-hash Laravel passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220925/how-to-re-hash-laravel-passwords)

Comment: I found a solution for my question here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36041533/2y-bcrypt-hashes-in-node-js